# org-mode TODO font-size

Tags: fonts, emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to get the org-mode face for TODO's to be the same size as the heading the TODO is within. This currently works for the face used for tags, as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

Using describe-face, the face for tags and the face for TODOs appear identical. Any idea why the TODO face is displayed at a completely different size?

```
Face: org-todo (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
Face for TODO keywords.

Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.

           Family: unspecified
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: unspecified
           Weight: unspecified
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: #dc752f
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
          Inherit: nil
```

```
Face: org-agenda-structure (sample) (customize this face)

Documentation:
Face used in agenda for captions and dates.

Defined in ‘org-faces.el’.

           Family: unspecified
          Foundry: unspecified
            Width: unspecified
           Height: unspecified
           Weight: unspecified
            Slant: unspecified
       Foreground: #c56ec3
DistantForeground: unspecified
       Background: unspecified
        Underline: unspecified
         Overline: unspecified
   Strike-through: unspecified
              Box: unspecified
          Inverse: unspecified
          Stipple: unspecified
             Font: unspecified
          Fontset: unspecified
          Inherit: nil
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info (Applies to StackOverflow too.)

Comment: Whoops, thanks Drew.

Comment: Don't know to fix this, but when I do: `(get-text-property (point) 'face)` I'm getting just `org-todo` when `(point)` is in a `TODO` and I'm getting a list of `(org-tag org-level-1)` when `(point)` is in a `:tag:`. I guess the latter sets the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the font sizes in headings will be fixed in org 9.5 thanks to the [Protesilaos contribution](https://protesilaos.com/codelog/2020-09-24-org-headings-adapt/).